# Name for expert sizing by a tailor

Tags: terminology

I remember reading years ago about a skill of some traditional tailors, possibly by special training or from experience. The skill was in judging by eye, to an unnatural accuracy, all the size parameters of a client without ever using a tape measure.

I have seen this particular skill used on film and TV to characterize old Jewish tailors. It's a bit of a trope actually. I should like to know the name for that skill, or its practitioner. I know some were trained in Gateshead UK so I think it has a British English term, although possibly the term is a Yiddish borrowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rock of Eye**

Example sentence including a definition:

> For interim fittings, "Rock Of Eye" (which means trained freehand
> based on an experienced artistic eye to match the item to the wearer,
> trusting the eye over unyielding scripted approach), drawing and
> cutting inaccuracies are overcome by the fitting.

[[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suit)

I could not find a Jewish term for that.

I found *rock of eye* by searching "a tailor who can fit by eye" (which returned about 83,500,000 results). The first sentence from the first result returned follows:

> If one enters the world of tailoring (in any era), it is usually not
> long before you hear of some mythical era of tailoring when tailors
> could do everything with regards to drafting and fitting with their
> ‘rock of eye’. — James Williams (historical taylor)

From "Developing the Tailor’s ‘Rock of Eye’" (2 OCTOBER 2018). [[historical-tailoring.com]](https://www.historical-tailoring.com/2018/10/developing-the-tailors-rock-of-eye/)

Comment: I grew up knowing a variation used in Derbyshire in other sectors such as mechanics and joinery which was "Rack o' th' eye an' a bit o' string".  However this did not carry the connotation of great accuracy, more like connotations of "fitting where it touches"

Comment: @KannE Having grown up knowing "rack o' th' eye" (standard English "rack of _the_ eye") "rock of eye" sounds odd to me. "Rack of eye" makes more sense to me if the expression is English rather than Yiddish as "rack" could be either a corruption of "reckoning" or a reference to estimating something visually when it's spread out on a rack. Either way it sounds to me as though one of the expressions is derived from the other but I make no claims for either being the original.